# Receive Object with String key from Map in transform method

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a strange problem with these lines of code(the for loop is just for my debugging):

```
  protected final List<Long> extractIdFromResult(Map<String, Object> pResult, String pKey) {
    for (String key : pResult.keySet()) {
      Object o = pResult.get(key);
      if (null == o){
        System.out.println("is null");
      }
    }
    return new SqlArrayExtractor<Long>(pResult.get(pKey)).extract(new Transformer() {
      @Override
      public Long transform(Object pInput) {
        return Long.valueOf(((BigDecimal) pInput).longValue());
      }
    });
  }
```

the method is called to extract id's(Longs) from a StoredProcedure.
`is null` is never written to the console and I never enter `if (null == o){` because `o` is not null.
Nevertheless if I enter `public Long transform(Object pInput)` `pInput` is always null!

How can that happen? That line works pretty good: `Object o = pResult.get(key);`

Thanks for your help

Stefan

Comment: What is `SqlArrayExtractor`? Your own class or from some library?

Comment: Are you certain the value of `pKey` is contained within the `pResult.keySet()`?

Comment: hmmm. own class... :) thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chance that pKey is not available in map so run the following code to check if it is. 
The loop will never pring null because you are iterating though keyset which you got from the map.

```
protected final List<Long> extractIdFromResult(Map<String, Object> pResult, String pKey) {
    System.out.println("is pKey available in map "+pResult.get(pKey));
    // There is a chance that the pKey can be something which is not available in the map.
    return new SqlArrayExtractor<Long>(pResult.get(pKey)).extract(new Transformer() {
      @Override
      public Long transform(Object pInput) {
        return Long.valueOf(((BigDecimal) pInput).longValue());
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: no it does not it checks for key not pKey. Object o = pResult.get(key); which is from the maps keyset

Comment: Then you will need to show us SqlArrayExtractor code.